# How to read data from an NI DAQ USB-6259?

Tags: sensor, driver, electronics

I have a sensor for which I'm forced to use a NI DAQ to read data from. And I have a USB-6259 to do so.

[image]

I don't want to connect the DAQ directly to my laptop because [it has messed it up before](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/BSOD-nipxibrc-sys-causing-blue-screen-error/td-p/3644635).

I know there is a [Low Cost USB DAQ Driver for use with Raspberry Pi for  NI USB-6008/6009 devices](https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Labs-Toolkits/Low-Cost-USB-DAQ-Driver-for-use-with-Raspberry-Pi/ta-p/3533944). But my question is if this is compatible with USB-6259? and If not how I can modify the driver for my specific DAQ?

P.S.1. From [official NI page](http://www.ni.com/nisearch/app/main/p/bot/no/ap/tech/lang/en/pg/1/sn/catnav:du,n8:3478.41.181.5495,ssnav:ndr/) there are Linux NI-DAQmx drivers for Mandriva, SUSE and RedHat distros. Most probably they are compiled for x86 OS not the arm versions. Any chance we can use those drivers on an arm version of those OSes?

P.S.2. This is the reply I got from NI technical support:

> ... unfortunately that's a community driver which I cant support you with. We have the Instrument Driver Network on the National Instruments site which is dedicated to third party drivers, and includes support for modifying drivers.
>
> I would also recommend trying the driver with the USB-6259 anyway as often our devices use identical protocols...

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use binaries compiled for x86 on arm without some kind of x86 emulation, all i can suggest is if you have a pi to hand then try it. most NI stuff tries to use the same/similar command sets however as this is a different device it will have a different USB product ID, so you have have to (if possible) change that in the driver

Comment: note on further inspection, the driver in those files is distributed as a precompiled binary, so you will not be able to change the product ID.

Answer (score 1):

NI's NIKAL stuff uses proprietary kernel modules, therefore is not allowed to use the linux USB subsystem. kmod will refuse to load these modules - for your own legal protection. If you override it, you're breaking the license, therefore loosing the right to use Linux at all.

Just don't ever buy any NI hardware, if you're ever intenting to use it outside the Windoze world, especially w/ Linux.

This company is just completely ignorant to the FOSS community. And by reading the nikal glue source code, one can easily see that these folks are absolute beginners in linux kernel development. (they actually manage to write their code in a really arch- and even subarch-specific - therefore completely unportable - way).